Inverse Laplace Transform of $(1-2\exp(-s))^{-1}$?
Is there an expression for the inverse Laplace Transform of $(1-2\exp(-s))^{-1}$?
The numeric solution looks unusual


$e^{-ns}$ is the Laplace transform of the measure $\delta_{n}(dx).$ And $$\frac{1}{1-2e^{-s}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^ne^{-ns}$$ is the Laplace transform of the unbounded measure $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n\delta_{n}(dx).$$
